# Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 4 - Getting NullPointerException due to SessionFactory being null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to convert my very small app to Spring 3.2 and Hibernate 4, but I can't get it to run properly with sessions.  Some info below this paragraph, but ultimately the sessionFactory is always null everytime it gets to the DAO and I can't figure out why.

**Comparing the console to Hibernate 3, Hibernate 3 shows this upon startup:**
Nov 23, 2012 10:51:52 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean buildSessionFactory
INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory

**Stack trace:**
java.lang.NullPointerException
dao.CSSDAOImpl.selectAllCSS(CSSDAOImpl.java:21)

**hibernate-cfg.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:derby:C:\Users\Steven\MyDB"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="net.form" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.form.StyleChooser</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="CSSDAO" class="dao.CSSDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**DAO:**

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import net.form.StyleChooser;

public class CSSDAOImpl implements CSSDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List selectAllCSS() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List l = session.createCriteria(StyleChooser.class).list();
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
        return l;
    }

    @Transactional
    public StyleChooser selectCSSById(Integer ID) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        StyleChooser sc = (StyleChooser) session.get(StyleChooser.class, ID);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();        
        return sc;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Integer insertCSS(StyleChooser insertCSS) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Integer id = (Integer) session.save(insertCSS);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
        return id;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteCSS(Integer CSSId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        StyleChooser sc = (StyleChooser) session.get(StyleChooser.class, CSSId);
        session.delete(sc);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateCSS(StyleChooser cssWithNewValues) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(cssWithNewValues);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();        
    }
}
```

Accessing DAO...

```
package net.controllers;

import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import net.form.StyleChooser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController;
import dao.CSSDAOImpl;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/stylechoosertable.html")
public class IndexController extends MultiActionController {

    Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(
            "C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/Programming/workspace/CSSGeneratorHibernate4/WebContent/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml");
    BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);
    CSSDAOImpl dao = (CSSDAOImpl) beanFactory.getBean("CSSDAO");

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showIndex(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        List<StyleChooser> styleChooser = dao.selectAllCSS();
        return new ModelAndView("stylechoosertable", "styleChooser", styleChooser);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are getting NPE because the service method(if there's one) that invokes your dao method is likely not declared as "@transactional" you seem to mix manual transaction management with "tx annotation driven" approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Spring configuration file make the following change:

```
<bean id="CSSDAO" class="dao.CSSDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Now, in CSSDAOImpl remove all the static modifiers:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

That should fix the NPE!

Comment: Thanks!  Although I'm not getting a NPE anymore, I'm now getting a:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
 at dao.CSSDAOImpl.selectAllCSS(CSSDAOImpl.java:21)

Comment: Have you tried opening the session first? Ie  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

Comment: That was it...and the deletes and updates wouldn't work unless I begin a transaction before the query execution and flush/commit afterwards.  My Dao is a huge mess now, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things nice and clean you should use @Transactional-Annotation in all methods and not open the sessions manually but always with sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). ...

I suppose you wanted to to do it that way anyways since you use tx: annotation-driven and have already imported the annotation.

Alternatively to Muel's answer, you could also use a @Autowired-Annotation on the setSessionFactory()-method.

Comment: Yea I'm pretty much trying to convert my old program using ancient MVC and Hibernate code into the newer versions (hibernate template before).  I'm having difficulties at some points though.  The way I have it now "works".  I added one of my controller classes' code to the question (ignore the MVC portion, I'll fix that later) and reposted my newer code in the other two.  How exactly does the DAO get "accessed" using sessionFactory?  It looks like sessionFactory is initialized upon startup, but creating a new DAO object nulls it out.

Comment: New dao being CSSDAO dao = new CSSDAOImpl();.  The resource and beanfactory keep the sessionFactory from being null, but I still have to open a session.  So I guess the second question would be, how does the session get created from the factory in the first place?

Comment: Well, the point of adding the @Transactional-Annotation is that you don't have to open a transaction and create a session manually which you still are doing. Normally, all you would need in your selectAllCSS()-method would be return (List<StyleChooser>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(StyleChooser.class).list()        Also if you autowire your sessionFactory you don't have to refer to it in the DAO configuration.

Comment: Also normally you would work with an ApplicationContext: Rename your hibernate.cfg.xml to applicationContext.xml and use like that:   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"applicationContext.xml"});

Comment: Now add your DAO as an attribute to your service-class (or in your case directly to the controller) and autowire it. Now define your controller as a bean and create it with context.getBean("indexController",IndexController.class) Should make things easier. I hope I could help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20190/discussion-between-user1795832-and-holger-pappenstiel)